# Using Composer to install yii 2.0 , error message confuses me

Tags: php, yii, windows-xp, composer-php

I am trying to get yii working on my machine, using the composer method of installation.I am pretty sure I installed composer correctly, based on the errors I am getting.

```
    Environment: 
    Win XP
    Xampp install version xampp-win32-1.8.2-6-VC9-installer.exe
    Xampp seems to be working fine. 
PHP 5.4.22
MySQL  5.5.34
Apache 2.4.7
phpMyAdmin 4.0.9
```

I installed Composer (since I got the error message below, I assume composer is installed fine)

But when I get to the next step in the YII install procedure (cut/paste right off the install instructions for yii 2.0), I get this error.

```
C:\XAMPP>php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0->beta4"
Could not open input file: composer.phar
C:\XAMPP>
```

Yii install Instructions are pretty weak. Am I in the right directory? Where would I find the missing file ? What am I doing wrong ? I just don't have a clue, since I don't know anything about composer and have enough to learn right now. I tired a search of here, also the yiiframework site, but can find no mention of this issue.  Most of the install problems seem to date to when it was in early development. All help or pointers appreciated.

Comment: do you have composer.phar in the directory?

Comment: find out where your composer.phar file is installed

Comment: @Melbourne2991  I have no composer.phar   file on my computer .  Should I ? Or do I have to create an empty one somewhere? Does that mean the composer install failed, even though it seems to run fine ?

Comment: @onegun No composer.phar anywhere on computer.  Does that mean install failed ?

Comment: try install it at https://getcomposer.org/

Comment: @onegun   I ran the install again, everything looks fine. No errors reported  Same error when I try to install yii .  And I still have no composer.phar file on my computer.   arrrrghgghh

Comment: u are running on mac or using gitbash on window?

Comment: Windows NT,  Have gitbash and gitGUI installed. Used gitGUI a couple of times. Never used gitBash

Comment: @onegun  
Windows NT, Have gitbash and gitGUI installed. Used gitGUI a couple of times. Never used gitBash –

Comment: i am not sure how you install the composer, however for me i usually go to my directory of project, then download to there using gitbash